# setValue based on if condition for undefined values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

really struggling with this, any help will be appreciated. I'm very sorry if my formatting is bad, I don't post here much. Please don't ban my question if you aren't happy with the formatting, just tell me what to do next time perhaps.

```
//Parse the JSON data
var params = JSON.stringify(e.postData.contents);
params = JSON.parse(params);
var myData = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var firstname = myData.firstname;
  var name = myData.name;
  var surname = myData.surname;
  
//Get the last row without data
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Leads");
var lastRow = Math.max(sheet.getLastRow(),1);
sheet.insertRowAfter(lastRow);
 
//Get current timestamp
var timestamp = new Date();
 
//Insert the data into the sheet
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 2).setValue(firstname);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 3).setValue(surname);
```

What I'm trying to achieve is in this row

```
sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 2).setValue(firstname);
```

I would like the value appended to be firstname OR name, in the same row, in the same column. name comes from the var name, just like firstname.

Comment: If I understood your question. Why don't you simply try: `sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 2).setValue(firstname+" "+name);` ? Could you try that and let me know if it worked?

Comment: Hi Mario, thanks for your input. It's sort of working however it is showing "undefined" either before or after the other one is used. So we have 2 forms, one custom field is called firstname, the other is name. It depends on which form, so it shouldn't actually be firstname+name i.e James James, it must be either one that was completed

Comment: Let me know if my answer worked for you. Otherwise please provide your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question and your comment, you can check whether `name` is `undefined` and then set a value based on that.

Use this:

```
  if (typeof name == 'undefined'){ 
      sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 2).setValue(firstname);
  }
  else {
      sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 2).setValue(name);
  }
```

Instead of this:

```
sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 2).setValue(firstname);
```

Comment: Marios, this worked! Thank you so much, really appreciate it!